# Will the character encoding(charset) declaration apply to the HTML file after saving it on my hard disk in following scenario?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System on my laptop. I'm learning HTML on this laptop from W3Schools HTML Tutorial(The Best in Class Tutorial available on internet).

I wrote following HTML code into simple Notepad editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I named this file as index.html and was trying to save on my hard disk. While doing so I changed the option from Encoding drop-down box from `ANSI` to `UTF-8` and then saved the file on my hard disk.

So my question without using the proper syntax for character encoding i.e.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

into `<head>` tag of HTML page will the character encoding get apply to the file index.html which I saved to my hard disk.

If yes how without adding a code for it? If no why even after setting the encoding type before saving the file?

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding of the file itself only has to do with how the content of the file is saved. Special characters etc. How the file is viewed is a completely different matter. Depending on the server, the file will either base its encoding on the server-side setup (httpd.conf, for instance), or if it's served via PHP, what settings are set up in php.ini. If the server, for some reason, does not use any of those settings, the `<meta>`-tag in the HTML might be used, and then it should match the method it's saved with, since if not, characters might be shown either broken, wrong, or just like gibberish.